# "He tells Reince and I" sounds wrong, doesn't it?

Tags: grammar

The following is quoted from The Washington Post of yesterday:

“If you think they’re going to give you your country back without a fight, you are sadly mistaken,” Bannon said in reference to the media and opposition forces. “Every day, it is going to be a fight.”
He continued, “And that is what I’m proudest about Donald Trump. All the opportunities he had to waver off this, all the people who have come to him and said, ‘Oh, you’ve got to moderate’ — every day in the Oval Office, he tells Reince and I, ‘I committed this to the American people, I promised this when I ran, and I’m going to deliver on this.’ ”

Towards the end of this quote, Bannon says, "he [Trump] tells Reince and I, ..."
Is this grammatically acceptable? Shouldn't he say instead, "he tells Reince and me, ...?"

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Looks like a hypercorrection, but who knows....?

Comment: No, it is not acceptable. But delusional hyper corrector types get this wrong all the time and come out sounding the opposite of smart or well educated.